# Practical example of nodejs 10 asynchronous iteration, e.g. what kind of problem will it solve better than stream?

Tags: node.js, async-await, stream

I have a basic idea of asynchronous iteration and how it work compared to stream, e.g.

With stream I will code like this

```
const stream = fs.createReadStream(filepath);
stream.on('data', chunk => {
  console.log(`Read: ${chunk}`);
});
stream.on('end', () => {
  console.log('EOF');
});
```

With asynchronous iteration I can code like this,

```
const stream = fs.createReadStream(filepath);
for await (const chunk of stream) {
  console.log(`Read: ${chunk}`);
}
console.log('EOF');
```

But I am yet to see what is the advantage it provides over stream ?

--- update ---

I read though the chapter "Asynchronous iteration" in the book ["Exploring ES2018 and ES2019"](https://exploringjs.com/es2018-es2019/ch_asynchronous-iteration.html) and I still feel asynchronous iteration is a rather convoluted language feature. The chapter mentioned WHATWG Streams are async iterables. But I have yet to see the practical use of WHATWG Streams too.

Comment: As nodejs is single threaded we don't want blocking code, as IO operations tends to block it, we avoid this situation by async.

Comment: @HarshVishwakarma The stream code doesn't block, except for when processing the `chunk` or the `end`. The `async` code might even take more time running the javascript that the syntax hides.

Comment: @Matt totally agree and that was why I yet to see the reason of using that. And hence my question.

Comment: the difference is going to be pretty negligible though :) Personally I end up wrapping most streams in some form of promise so it fits in with the rest of my code. So I would normally just use the async API now, when available and I'm not doing any fancy piping.

Comment: @Matt I actually did some "fancy" piping so I think I will stick with stream.

Answer (score 0):

Now I have a better understanding of async generator vs stream and I would like provide an answer for my own question.

With async generators it is easier to manage data flow. The part that creates data clearly separates from the part that consume the data, especially when these 2 parts are not written by the same author.

If using stream, the stream is in control and **pushes** data to the consumer; if using async iteration the consumer is in control and **pulls** data from the stream.

[Goodbye Transform-Streams, long live ES9 Async Generators](https://medium.com/@andreasimonecosta/goodbye-transform-streams-long-live-es9-async-generators-86e60284fb80) provides a good example to rewrite the transform stream logic with async generators.

[Javascript Streams vs Generators](https://dev.to/micahriggan/streams-and-generators-36e1) provide another example to implement the same function with both stream and generator, let us compare their difference easily.